# Collapse span into two columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**UPDATED**
I have tow columns with TwitterBootstrap `span7` and `span5` like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span7">Column 1</div>
<div class="span5">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

In `span5` I have content in a definition list `<dl>`
on tablet and mobile screens (767px and below) collapses into this:

```
|     span7     |   
|     span5     |
```

this makes the collapsed `span5` extremely tall and thin, therefore I would need to split the information in `span5` into two columns like this:

```
|     span7     |   
| span5 | span5 |
```

Any suggestion how to do this without any major hassle?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to write in the new 'span5' columns. Can you make it clearer ?

Comment: Orabîg I hope it is a bit clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you have to admit that only you can specify how you want your "span5" content to be split. It can't be guessed by the browser. (maybe you'll want every other line, or split in in the middle...)

So, let's assume your original content is :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span7">Span 7</div>
  <div class="span5">
    <div>Span 5-1</div>
    <div>Span 5-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which makes

```
|       span7       |   
| span5-1 | span5-2 |
```

This post should be helpful : [Twitter Bootstrap: how to not scale columns to single row under 767px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419513/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-not-scale-columns-to-single-row-under-767px)

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to do better than be forced to write your content twice :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span7">Span 7</div>
  <div class="span5 hidden-phone">
    <div>Span 5-1</div>
    <div>Span 5-2</div>
  </div>
    <div class="mobile-one visible-phone">Span 5-1</div>
    <div class="mobile-two visible-phone">Span 5-2</div>
</div>
```

(you can test it at http://bootply.com/86089)

I'll post another solution if I manage to find something better...