# "Pivoting" a layout with Bootstrap 3 fluid grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just starting with `Bootstrap 3` and struggling to find a fluid (responsive) solution for the required grid.

Simplified it should look like the following

**for desktop and tablets:**

```
------------+---------------+-----------
 Label 1.1   Label 2.1       Label 3.1 
 Label 1.2   Label 2.2       Label 3.2
```

**for phones**:

```
----------+----------
 Label 3.1  Label 3.2     
 Label 2.1  Label 2.2
 Label 1.1  Label 1.2
```

As you can see the components need to be stacked in 3 columns on a larger screens while forming 3 lines with 2 columns each on smaller ones.

I unsuccessfully tried three blocks with a pair of components in each like the one below. They are all wrapped into a `container` and a `row`.

```
   <div class="col-md-4 ">
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
           <label>Label 1.1</label.1>
           <label>Label 2.1</label>
       </div> 
    </div>
```

I also tried to splitting each label into it's own `<div class="col-sm-6">` and it didn't work for me as well.

On top of it (as you can see), the order needs to be reversed vertically.  I was thinking about `push` and `pull` but they work horizontally.

Is it even possible with pure Bootstrap (no custom CSS). Am I missing something basic here? Please point me into the right direction.

**EDIT:** (03/26/2014)

I believe that I found a solution to a reverse ordering.  Create `sm` layout with the appropriate order and then use `push` and `pull` to swap 1st and 3rd fields in each row in a horizontal layout on `md` and `lg` devices.

Still not sure how to achieve the desired layouts *organically* (i.e. without field duplication with `visible` and `hidden` classes).

Comment: I don't have a full answer but this comes really close : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419513/twitter-bootstrap-how-to-not-scale-columns-to-single-row-under-767px

Comment: Sorry, but not close enough.  With `Boostrap 3` *that* example is easily solvable without any custom CSS by separating the whole column  into separate `<div class="row"> elements and then applying column rules only to the children of the required row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I didn't miss anything, this matches your two layouts specified:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right'>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-12'>3.1</div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-12'>3.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right'>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-12'>2.1</div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-12'>2.2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right'>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-12'>1.1</div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-12'>1.2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, you use the pull-right to make the top pull to the right, which essentially reverses the order when stacked.

Comment: Yes, it works.  I was thinking about putting `col-md-4 md-push-6` on the left, leaving center without, and `col-md-4 col-md-pull-6` - on the right.  Didn't even know that `quick floats` can be used this way.  To think of it I'm not sure that I understood floats at all.